# Infinite loop on yes/no ksh

Tags: bash, shell, infinite-loop, ksh

I have an annoying issue that seems to cause and infinite loop and I can't work out why. If I call the following function, it keeps repeating the yes/no options infinitely down the screen until I crash out.

```
AuditUpload() {
    clear
    echo "Audit report generated successfully"
    echo " "
    echo "Do you wish to upload qhub_audit.csv? (1 = Yes/2 = No):"
    sleep 1
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) AuditUploader; Auditvi; exit;;
        No ) echo "Upload cancelled"; Auditvi; exit;;
    esac
    done
}
```

I put the sleep in to see if it would remedy the issue but it still does the same. This issue seems to be very intermittent and doesn't happen every time. This script is written in korn shell (ksh).

AuditUploader function:

```
AuditUploader() {
echo "Uploading qhub_audit.csv to $HOST..." 
curl -v -T qhub_audit.csv -# ftp://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: Cannot upload qhubload.csv" 
        exit
    else
        clear
        echo "qhub_audit.csv has been put on $HOST successfully"

        tput cup 5 5
        echo "Copy and paste this link into internet explorer to download:"
        tput cup 7 5
        echo "ftp://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/qhub_audit.csv"
        read LINK
    fi
}
```

Auditvi function:

```
Auditvi() {
clear
echo "Do you wish to view qhub_audit.csv? (1 = Yes/2 = No):"
sleep 1
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
    Yes ) vi qhub_audit.csv; exit;;
    No ) exit;;
    esac
done

}
```

Comment: What are AuditUploader and Auditvi?

Comment: When you enter `2` do you get an "Upload cancelled" message?

Comment: Hi chepner, they are other functions that are called when choosing option 1.

Comment: lurker, if it doesn't go nuts and actually works then it displays the "Upload cancelled" message as expected. If it goes nuts then it won't let you do anything until you crash out.

Comment: Keeps repeating sounds like something is feeding it empty strings (or spamming on the enter key). Giving select just about any input should cause it to terminate one way or another but giving it "no input" causes it to ask again.

Comment: Add `set -x` at the start of the function so you can track what it's doing

Comment: Hi Etan, I think that sounds like what is happening but I can't seem to get it to stop. rojomoke, if I put a set -x into the function it doesn't really display anyting of help:
`+ clear
+ echo Audit report generated successfully
+ echo
Audit report generated successfully
+ echo Do you wish to upload qhub_audit.csv? (1 = Yes/2 = No):

+ sleep 1
Do you wish to upload qhub_audit.csv? (1 = Yes/2 = No):
1) Yes
2) No
#?
1) Yes
2) No
#?
1) Yes
2) No
#?
1) Yes
2) No
#?
`

Comment: Before the `case` statement, you can add `echo debug: select reply is "'$REPLY'"`

Comment: How do you invoke `AuditUpload`? Do you pipe any input into it?

Comment: Nothing is piped to AuditUpload it just simply checks if there's a specific file there before hand

`if [ -f "$BRODIR/qhub_audit.unl" ]
then
        echo "Generating report headers"
        echo "rsh_id,Start date/time,End date/time,Time taken,Error," > qhub_auit.csv
       cat qhub_audit.unl >> qhub_audit.csv
        AuditUpload
        Auditvi
else
        echo "No report generated!"
        echo "Exiting..."
fi
`

Comment: That's what @chepner was after in his first question: he wanted to know what those functions (`AuditUpload` and `Auditvi`) actually do. If they're small, then perhaps post their source in your question rather than a comment so they can be more easily read.

Comment: @lurker I have now added the functions to my question.

Comment: Interesting. Based upon your comments, it looks like those aren't even being executed when you hit your infinite loop. I assume you are just running `AuditUpload` from a command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around it looks like it was looping whenever the 'curl' command returned a specific error which stopped the `kill $$` from working properly. I replaced `kill $$` with `exit 1` and amended the other functions accordingly. I also put in a contingency to use kermit in case the FTP failed. Anyway, this is what my code looks like now:

```
#########################################
# Upload quotehub audit report function #
#########################################
AuditUploader() {
    echo "Uploading qhub_audit.csv to $HOST..." 
    curl -v -T qhub_audit.csv -# ftp://$USER:$PASSWD@$HOST/ -m 10
        if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
            then
            echo "ERROR: Cannot upload qhubload.csv via FTP" 
            if [ ${term} = "tty1A" ]
                then
                echo "Attempting to download to modems server..."
                wermit -s qhub_audit.csv
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                    then
                    echo "Cannot upload to modems either!"
                    echo "This file will have to be downloaded manually"
                    exit 1
                else
                    clear
                    echo "qhub_audit.csv has been put on modems server successfully"
                    tput cup 5 5
                    echo "Copy and paste this link into START -> RUN to download:"
                    tput cup 7 5
                    echo "\\\\\\xxxxxxxx\download\general\qhub_audit.csv"
                    read LINK
                fi
            else
                echo "Upload failed!"
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            clear
            echo "qhub_audit.csv has been put on $HOST successfully"
            tput cup 5 5
            echo "Copy and paste this link into internet explorer to download:"
            tput cup 7 5
            echo "ftp://$USER:$PASSWD@$HOST/qhub_audit.csv"
            read LINK
        fi
}

#######################################################
# Function to prompt user to upload qhub audit report #
#######################################################
AuditUpload() {
    clear
    echo "Audit report generated successfully"
    echo ""
    echo "Do you wish to upload qhub_audit.csv? (y/n):"
    read REPLY
    case "$REPLY" in
        Y) AuditUploader; Auditvi; exit;;
        y) AuditUploader; Auditvi; exit;;
        N) Auditvi; exit;;
        n) Auditvi; exit;;
        *) echo "invalid option";;
    esac
}
######################################
# Function to view qhub audit report #
######################################
Auditvi() {
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]
        then
        exit 1
    else
        clear
        echo "Do you wish to view qhub_audit.csv? (y/n):"
        read REPLY
        case "$REPLY" in
            Y) vi qhub_audit.csv; exit;;
            y) vi qhub_audit.csv; exit;;
            N) exit;;
            n) exit;;
            *) echo "invalid option"; Pause; Auditvi;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

Thanks again guys for all your help.